How to keep Div centered without moving when populating or deleting other divs around it?
I've tried to keep the Plus card centered with the grid but couldn't get it to work. I also tried position: absolute but the cards go underneath it.
I need the div elements that are being added or deleted to go around the div that is permanently centered. The goal is to add new notes or delete notes with Javascript, but testing the design with css.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: #008f4b solid 6px;
}

.nav_container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #008f4b;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: #024731 solid 3px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}

li:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #00b85f;
}

.search_container {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.notes_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50vw;
  margin: auto;
}

.notes_wrapper {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-areas: "note note add_note note note", "note note note note note", ;
}

.note_card {
  grid-area: 'note';
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.add_card {
  grid-area: 'add_note';
  padding: 40px 20px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<div class="nav_container">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>All</li>
      <li>Recent</li>
      <li>Pinned</li>
      <li>Search</li>
      <!-- <li class="search_container"><image src="assets/Icons/search.svg"></image></li> -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="notes_container">
  <div class="notes_wrapper">
    <div class="note_card">
      <h3>Notes</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="note_card">
      <h3>Notes</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="add_card">+</div>
    <div class="note_card">
      <h3>Notes</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="note_card">
      <h3>Notes</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="note_card">
      <h3>Notes</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="note_card">
      <h3>Notes</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Why not put "the plus" as the beginning or end of your layout of notes. That would make sense if they are sorted chronologically and make it easier to make the whole thing responsive.

You can usegrid container, where all cards auto placed, and the plus button manually placed at the center.
Here is an example:


const grid = document.querySelector('#grid');

function addCard() {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className='card';
  div.innerHTML = '&times;';
  div.addEventListener('click', removeCard);
  grid.appendChild(div);
}

function removeCard() {
  card = grid.querySelector('.card');
  card?.remove();
}

for(let i=0; i<20; i++) addCard();
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 6px;
  margin: auto;
  width: fit-content;
  user-select: none;
}

.card {
  height: 50px;
  background: #f8e122;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#plus {
  height: 106px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 5;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

#plus-btn {
  background: #1626ef;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 68px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<div id="grid">
  <div id="plus" onCLick="addCard()">
    <div id="plus-btn">+</div>
  </div>
</div>



